# Python unicode error in linux but not windows

Tags: python, linux

I followed some guides to piece together this bit of python

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get(sys.argv[1])

html = BeautifulSoup(url.content,'html.parser')

for br in html.find_all("br"):
    br.replace_with(" ")

for tr in html.find_all('tr'):
    data = []   

    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        data.append(td.text.strip())

    if data:
        print("{}".format(','.join(data)))
```

In Windows it works as I expect it to.

In Linux I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "html2csv.py", line 19, in <module>
    print("{}".format(','.join(data)))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What do I need to change in my script to prevent this?
I read that you can ignore problem characters but some say this isn't the proper way to do it?
Not sure how to implement any of the solutions I found into what I have.

Comment: are you sure to be using the same version of python on both systems? (python 2.x vs python3.x)

Comment: Thanks this was the issue. "python script.py" defaulted to 2.7. I needed to run "python3 script.py"

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for wasting your time.

I was using...

```
python script.py
```

Which defaults to 2.7

What I needed to run is...

```
python3 script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it seems that coding in MS Windows leave some ghost chars (guess you can configure your IDE not to do so).

Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your script file as here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

import json
import os, sys

class CSV_LOADER():
    """
    Script that handles batch credentials (in CSV format), both locally and
    to remote machines.

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely your Python IO encoding is set to `ascii` for some reason (likely due to misconfigured system locale settings), so everything printed to standard output (and read from standard input) is interpreted as ASCII.

Set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `utf-8` before running your script (or better yet, ensure your system's `locale` settings are correct).